# Automate fasta sequence retrieve for many files

Tags: python, loops, fasta

I have a fasta file with many sequences as follow:

```
>gi|2765658|emb|Z78533.1|CIZ78533 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene
CGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
AATCCGGAGGACCGGTGTACTCAGCTCACCGGGGGCATTGCTCCCGTGGTGACCCTGATTTGTTGTTGGG
>gi|2765659|emb|Z78553.1|CIZ78553 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene
AATTTCAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
AATCCGGAGGACCGGTGTACTCAGCTCACCGGGGGCATTGCTCCCGTGGTGACCCTGATTTGTTGTTGGG
>gi|2765668|emb|Z78531.3|CIZ78531 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene
CGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
```

Also, I have a id.file with some gene ids that I want to retrieve the sequences from the fasta file and get the output with respective genes and sequences, for example:

```
gi|2765658|emb|Z78533.1|CIZ78533
gi|2765659|emb|Z78553.1|CIZ78553
```

My outputfile will be:

```
>gi|2765658|emb|Z78533.1|CIZ78533 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene
CGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
AATCCGGAGGACCGGTGTACTCAGCTCACCGGGGGCATTGCTCCCGTGGTGACCCTGATTTGTTGTTGGG
>gi|2765659|emb|Z78553.1|CIZ78553 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene
AATTTCAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
AATCCGGAGGACCGGTGTACTCAGCTCACCGGGGGCATTGCTCCCGTGGTGACCCTGATTTGTTGTTGGG
```

But I have many id.files (500 files - idfile1.txt idfile2.txt, idfile3.txt, etc.) with different groups of genes and I have a python script to do this job for only one file at a time, but I would like to do it for my 500 files at the same time. My python script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Bio import SeqIO

fasta_file = "fastafile.fa" # Input fasta file
wanted_file = "idfile1.txt" # Input interesting sequence IDs, one per line
result_file = "out1.fasta" # Output fasta file

wanted = set()
with open(wanted_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line != "":
            wanted.add(line)

fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open(fasta_file),'fasta')
with open(result_file, "w") as f:
    for seq in fasta_sequences:
        if seq.id in wanted:
            SeqIO.write([seq], f, "fasta")
```

How can I do a loop for it? 
I have only one fasta file, but many id files.
I am new in Python, so I am not sure how to do it. Or maybe I can run a shell script with a loop for this script? I am not sure because I need to include the file names on it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Id say `os` is your friend here.
Assuming that your folder contains several types of files, but all text files with ending `txt` shall be treated. I guess that every input file needs its own result file, so we have to take care of that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Bio import SeqIO
import os  

fasta_file = "fastafile.fa" # Input fasta file


mypath='/home/usr/data/mydatafolder'#your path here
for file in os.listdir(mypath):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):#as you probably have others there as well
        wanted_file=os.path.join(mypath,file)#absolute path to file

        wanted = set()###clearing for every new file
        with open(wanted_file) as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()
                if line:
                    wanted.add(line)

        result_file=os.path.join(mypath, 'result_'+wanted_file)
        #this puts the output of, e.g. idfile17.txt in result_idfile17.txt

        with open(result_file, "w") as f:
            for seq in fasta_sequences:
                if seq.id in wanted:
                    SeqIO.write([seq], f, "fasta")
```

or if you know how the file names are constructed, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Bio import SeqIO
import os  

fasta_file = "fastafile.fa" # Input fasta file
fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open(fasta_file),'fasta')

mypath='/home/usr/data/mydatafolder'#your path here

filenamelist=["idfile{}.txt".format(x) for x in range(100)]
#files from 0 to 99
### or maybe some specific numbers?
# filenamelist=["idfile{}.txt".format(x) for x in [1,20,30,50,117] ]


for file in filenamelist:
    wanted_file=os.path.join(mypath,file)#absolute path to file
    ####now the same thing as before
    wanted = set()###clearing for every new file
    with open(wanted_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                wanted.add(line)

    result_file=os.path.join(mypath, 'result_'+wanted_file)
    #this puts the output of, e.g. idfile17.txt in result_idfile17.txt
    with open(result_file, "w") as f:
        for seq in fasta_sequences:
            if seq.id in wanted:
                SeqIO.write([seq], f, "fasta")
```

Note that you could create easily an independent list for output file names as well.

Comment: Do you mean add this part in my original script? In the begging? And how about the the file names in my script (wanted file and output?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob`.  Add to the preamble (top of the file):

```
import glob
```

then replace

```
with open(wanted_file) as f:
```

with

```
for wanted_file in glob.glob("/path/to/files/id*.txt"):
    with open(wanted_file) as f:
       ...
```

assuming all FASTA file names are in the format `id*.txt` and are located in the `/path/to/files/` folder.  Make sure that you indent the following code correctly.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood. I need to add this part in my original python script? And remove the "wanted_file = "idfile1.txt""?

Answer (score 0):

I tried as suggested, but probably I am doing many mistakes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Bio import SeqIO
import glob

fasta_file = "fasta_final.fa" # Input fasta file

for wanted_file in glob.glob("/data/ids/id*.txt"):
    with open(wanted_file) as f:

        wanted = set()
        with open(wanted_file) as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()
                if line != "":
                    wanted.add(line)

fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open(fasta_file),'fasta')
with open(result_file, "w") as f:
    for seq in fasta_sequences:
        if seq.id in wanted:
            SeqIO.write([seq], f, "fasta")
```

But is not working, error message is:
NameError: name 'result_file' is not defined

I included the result file, but is expected to have many results files, depending the id file. I am not sure what to do!

Comment: First, you shouldn't post a failed try as an answer. You may add this as an edit to the original post. Second, as you now did not define result_file anywhere, this is expected. You need to define an output file name for every pass of the loop. See my answer for that.